# How to change the gravity of the google play connection pop-up menu?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, leaderboard

I'm doing an little game application on Android. My main activity extends BaseGameActivy so it is connecting to google play automatically when I open the apps. 
I'm trying to display the 'Connecting' pop-up menu on the top of the activity and it doesn't work. The google docs says

> You can customize how the Google Play Games 'Connecting' pop-up is displayed during sign-in >by using setShowConnectingPopup().

I tried this line in my 'onCreate' in the main activity:

```
Games.GamesOptions.builder().setShowConnectingPopup(true, Gravity.TOP);
```

but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Where you define the **Builder()** for your **GoogleApiClient** you need to add the Api you want and define the desired **GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions** for that particular Api (and don't forget to call the **build()** method). In your case you should do something like this in your **onCreate()**:

```
        GoogleApiClient.ApiOptions apiOptions = Games.GamesOptions.builder().setShowConnectingPopup(true, Gravity.TOP).build();
        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Games.API, apiOptions)
            .build();
```